# Undefined params in react native navigation

Tags: react-navigation

i am trying to pass parameters through navigation

this is the access to ProfileScreen in my DrawerSection

```
 <DrawerItem
                        icon={({color, size}) => (
                            <Icon
                            name="ios-person"
                            color={color}
                            size={size}
                            />
                        )}
                        label="Account"
                        onPress={() => {props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen',{ params: {text: 'test'}})}}
                    />
```

and this is my ProfileScreen

```
const ProfileScreen = ({route}) => {


console.log(route);
```

the log then give me this result

```
 {"key": "Account-qkhK3r7vkx", "name": "Account", "params": undefined}
```

i don't understand what i'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are trying to access a nested screen?
If so you will have to modify the parameters you pass to the navigate function.

[react-native navigation 5 undefined params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319294/react-native-navigation-5-undefined-params)