# react-native unable to acess navigation.getParam('imageData', 'NO-ID');

Tags: react-native

I am passing a value from screen one

```
navigation.setParams({imageData:images[0]})
navigation.navigate('screenTwo')
```

OR

```
navigation.navigate('screenTwo',{imageData:images[0]})
```

But I am not able to access the value in screenTwo using

```
const screenTwo = ({navigation}) =>{
const itemId = navigation.getParam('imageData', 'NO-ID');
}
```

I am getting error

```
 ERROR  TypeError: navigation.getParam is not a function. (In 'navigation.getParam('imageData', 'NO-ID')', 'navigation.getParam' is undefined)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
```

I tried below code in the same page
navigation.setParams({imageData:images[0]})
console.log(navigation.params);

output :  LOG  undefined

Comment: Please write you version of `react-navigation`

Comment: "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",

Comment: use route.params or you can also use useRoute hook from react navigation

Answer (score 1):

### No more getParam

Previously we could also use `navigation.getParam('someParam', 'defaultValue')` to get a param value. It addressed 2 things:

Guard against `params` being `undefined` in some cases
Provide a default value if the `params.someParam` was `undefined` or `null`

Official documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#the-navigation-prop

### Your solution

```
const screenTwo = ({navigation, route}) => {
    const itemId = route.params?.imageData ?? 'NO-ID';
}
```

Online example: https://snack.expo.io/@vasylnahuliak/stackoverflow-68240142

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details', { text: 'Hello, I am text from params' })}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const DetailsScreen = ({route}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details screen</Text>
      <Text style={{padding: 40}}>{JSON.stringify(route.params)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <RootStack.Navigator>
        <RootStack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <RootStack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried your approach in different pages it didn't work,

i then tried in the same page
  navigation.setParams({imageData:images[0]})
  console.log(navigation.params?.imageData ?? 'defaultValue')
output : LOG  defaultValue

Comment: i tried your approach in different pages it didn't work,
route page2:{"key": "New Post-S7WyANsZ2hSy7hcxvPPa0", "name": "New Post", "params": undefined} 
i then tried in the same page
  navigation.setParams({imageData:images[0]})
  console.log(route.params?.imageData ?? 'defaultValue')
                console.log(route)
but in same page the values are coming. Why can't i access the value in second page?

Comment: params set in page one can be accessed in page one itself, in page two it becomes null

Comment: Please try my online example. Maybe it help you

Comment: @souradeepmajumdar you need pass params in second argument in navigate method `navigation.navigate('Details', { text: 'Hello, I am text from params' })}`

Comment: i have tried it too
navigation.navigate('pagetwo',{imageData:images[0]})
in debugger i can see the values set in page one, but the moment it navigates to page two route.params become undefined. i have no idea how to fix this

Comment: you case is similar to https://snack.expo.io/@vasylnahuliak/stackoverflow-68240142 ?

Comment: I got the solution it's a combination of your and bora's approach. thanks for the help, can you see the solution in the answer section

Answer (score 1):

solution for me worked in two-part:

1. problem of passing the param from first page to second page
   solution: [react-native navigation 5 undefined params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319294/react-native-navigation-5-undefined-params)

   navigation.navigate('MainNavigationName', {
   screen: 'ScreenNameToNavigate',
   params: { propertyKey: propertyValue },
   })
2. reading values from route

   const itemId = route.params?.imageData ?? 'NO-ID';

thanks a lot Vasyl and Bora